# Exporting controller is not working in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple application to display contacts/users from my database. I have done the following based on some reference found in online.  I am getting error 'Can't found the module '..path/controller/ContactController'

1. Is this the proper way to use MVC. Because I found may mays in online to use MVC. Please suggest some example of using MVC in Node js.

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');

var  app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/contact");

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/view');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var controllerPath = __dirname + '/controller';

require('./models/contact')(mongoose);
['Contact'].forEach(function(controller){
require(controllerPath + '/' +  controller +  'Controller')(app, mongoose);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
})
```

controller/contact.js

```
var Contact = require('../models/Contact');
var ContactController = function(app,mongoose){
var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact');
app.get('/contact', function(req, req){
    Contact.find({},function(err, contactinfo){

         res.render("contact",{contact: contactinfo });
    });
})
}
module.exports = ContactController;
```

models/contact.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
cid: String,
name: String,
phon: Number,
contactwith: String

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SimpleAuth",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "start": "nodemon app.js"
       },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.0.0rc4",
         "jade": "*",
          "mongoose": "*",
          "nodemon": "*"
         }
      }
```

Comment: Missing a `var` keyword before `ContactController` is declared.

Comment: @S.D I added 'var' as you mentioned still getting the same error

Comment: try changing the names of files to lower case, in some versions of node that happens to be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change forEach loop as follows

```
['contact'].forEach(function(controller){
  require(controllerPath + '/' +  controller)(app, mongoose);
});
```

Comment: yes, it's worked, Thanks.  Now  I am getting an error can't overwrite 'Contact ' model once compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You require a wrong path.

```
require(controllerPath + '/' +  controller +  'Controller')(app, mongoose);
```

This concatenation doesn't match with this file name : controller/contact.js